# Anyway to implement Meteor like data subscription in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, meteor, socket.io

I am using Express.js for one of my projects, basically, what I am trying to achieve is simple:

1. the page displays a list of entries pulled from the data mongodb collection
2. when user adds an new entry, client side jQuery collects the input and fires an AJAX call  to the server script
3. server code adds the data to mongodb collection
4. server signals the client to re-render the templating code hence the list will be updated

where I am having problem is #4, as I mentioned, I would like to get the client to re-render the template with the updated data, instead of manipulating the dom using jQuery.

I have tried using socket.io, but using it together with .ajax, plus I have to pass the res variable around so I can do res.render is just a mess...

With Meteor.js, the data hot push (subscription) is done automatically, but there must be a way to do it with Express.js, right? Has anyone done this before? Some help PLEASE!!!

Comment: This is not how Meteor works. In Meteor the user's input is reflected in the local cache before the round-trip to the server which makes the action look instant (this is called latency compensation). Only then the client sends the change action to the server and waits for the confirmation. If confirmation is not received, client reverts the local changes.

Comment: You should understand how meteor works internally, then you can implement it yourself.

Comment: OMG... for so long, I've wanted to put my hands on Angular and just never got a chance to really understand it... now I think I know why I need it... yes, stupid as I am, took this long (since late 2012...)

Answer (score 0):

Without much work you could run a meteor server with the following:

/server/main.js

```
CollectionName = new Meteor.Collection("collectionName");

Meteor.publish("some_name", function() {
    return CollectionName.find();
});
```

---

Then you could have a simple nodejs app

```
npm install ddp
```

---

app.js

```
var DDPClient = require('ddp');

var connection = var ddpclient = new DDPClient({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000, //Port and IP of your meteor server
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    connection.subscribe('some_name');
}); 

ddpclient.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log("ddp message: " + msg);
});
```

Then when you add in something to your 'collectionName' collection you would get it back in your express app. Not perfectly optimal (since you have a meteor app in between your express app). But it gets the job done.